# Unable to install sass on linux

Tags: node.js, sass

I'm trying to install node-sass but getting error

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir 
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass'
 npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir 
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: 
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ 
 '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: Have you tried to install as administrator?

Comment: Thanks @Bernhard but I did that as sudo

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's bad practice installing things globally. Install it locally instead with `npm install node-sass --save-dev`

Comment: Opinion is like a `view` everybody has one

Comment: What happens when he wants to develop on another project, which has another version dependency for `node-sass`? Does he have to install the correct version globally each time he changes projects?

Answer (score 0):

Problem are the permissions which are executed not with root permissions

Looke here: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1098#issuecomment-133677759

> First you need to check your permissions is /usr/local/lib/node_modules. Most probably only root can write there.
>   If you decide to run sudo npm install -g node-sass make sure you read our TROUBLESHOOTING entry on permissions as well as npm documentation on permissions, because your sudo npm will run our installations scripts as nobody.

So I think using the `--unsafe-perm` flag should fix it.

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g node-sass
```

Comment: Am sorry @Bernhard Arti answered earlier so I tired that and it worked. So I accepted her answer. But it helped me thank you